# QNetworkReply, QNetworkAccessManager - download file by HTTPS - high cpu usage

Tags: c++, qt

I created file downloader with QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager in C++ with **Qt 5.12.3**.
When download file starts cpu usage rises to high values (especially on ARM device).

- Desktop - cpu i7@4GHz - Linux operating system:
  cpu usage is 2%-7% depending on download speed. Average cpu usage is 5% with max download speed which is 20 Mb/s. Cpu usage is same both on debug and release builds.
- SBC - ARM cpu @1,53Ghz - Linux operating system:
  cpu usage is 5%-50% depending on download speed. Average cpu usage is 40% with max download speed which is 20 Mb/s. Cpu usage checked with release build.

It is normal to have such high CPU usage when downloading files by HTTPS in Qt or I missing something?

Code:
Starting file download:

```cpp
  qDebug() << "HTTP: starting download FILE" << file_name << "from" << url.toString();
  QNetworkRequest req(url);
  req.setMaximumRedirectsAllowed(3);
  req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, http_user_agent);
  req.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
  req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
  const QByteArray range_header_value = "bytes=" + QByteArray::number(curr_file_size) + "-";
  req.setRawHeader("Range", range_header_value);

  net_reply = nam->get(req);
  net_reply->setReadBufferSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
  connect(net_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &file_downloader::operation_finished);
  connect(net_reply, &QNetworkReply::metaDataChanged, this, &file_downloader::metadata_changed);
  connect(net_reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &file_downloader::download_progress);
```

I reading content from `net_reply` every 250 msecs:

```cpp
read_buffer.append(net_reply->read(read_buffer_size));
if(read_buffer.size() >= read_buffer_size)
{
  const qint64 bytes_written = file->write(read_buffer);
  read_buffer.clear();
  if(bytes_written == -1)
  {
    qDebug() << "Error write to FILE:" << file->fileName() << ". Aborting download";
    QTimer::singleShot(0, net_reply, &QNetworkReply::abort);
  }
}
```

To minimize CPU usage I have tried to:

- read net_reply in `ReadyRead` signal with/without buffer,
- read net_reply only without save to file,
- read net_reply with `read` function and `readAll` function,
- use Callgrind and perf profiler in QtCreator - but both showing me high costs at not my code (eg.: q_SSL_read, __tpstrtab_dax_pte_fault_done)

Any advises or maybe these CPU usages are normal when downloading files by HTTPS?

Comment: How do these CPU usage measurements compare to e.g. `wget` on the same devices?

Comment: @Mike with `wget` cpu usages are pretty same. :O On desktop: 1%-5%, avg: 4%. On ARM device: 3%-45%, avg: 35%. Thanks @Mike.

Answer (score 0):

CPU usages with `wget` and downloading by Qt are pretty same. Therefore I think theses CPU usages are normal.